# tvOS UITabBarController start unfocused

Tags: focus, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbar, tvos

I have a simple tvOS application starting with a `UITabBarController` and I wish the main view to have the focus when the app launches, not the tab bar.

I've tried playing with `self.tabBarController.tabBar.userInteractionEnabled` to remove temporarily the focus, but in vain. (Besides I do no like that kind of workaround)

Any clue?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The above approach mostly works but does not allow you to select a tab bar item with click as it returns the tabBar in that case when it should return the selectedItem. Here is an improved version which solves this by returning [super preferredViewController] instead of tabBar in the normal case. This version also hides the tab bar with alpha at launch so that it doesn't flicker in. There are probably more elegant ways to do the hiding.

```
@interface MWTabBarController ()

@property (nonatomic, assign) BOOL firstTime;

@end

@implementation MWTabBarController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.firstTime = YES;
    self.tabBar.alpha = 0;
    [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0 target:self selector:@selector(unAlphaTabBar) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
}

- (void) unAlphaTabBar
{
    self.tabBar.alpha = 1;
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
}

- (UIView *)preferredFocusedView {
    if (self.firstTime) {
        self.firstTime = NO;
        return self.selectedViewController.preferredFocusedView;
    }
    else {
        return [super preferredFocusedView];
    }
}
```

Comment: It's strange that you mention a flicker, because with this solution the tabbar never gets the focus, so it is never displayed. Besides, both on the simulator and the tv nothing flickers. But the call to super is better solution, I'll edit my answer.

Comment: Weird... With the beta3 there is a flicker (not visible with the beta2) so thanks for your answer.

Comment: Yeah I don't know if the flicker is a bug or what. I did notice that even with the 1 second delay I did see it flicker one time, so I have extended it to 2 seconds. But hopefully in GM this will not be needed.

Comment: Thanks, I'll extend to 2 seconds.

Answer (score 6):

My original solution no longer works on tvOS 9.3, so I found a new one with subclassing `UITabBarController`:

```
@interface TVTabBarController : UITabBarController
@property (nonatomic) BOOL useDefaultFocusBehavior;
@end
@implementation TVTabBarController
- (UIView *)preferredFocusedView {
    return self.useDefaultFocusBehavior ? [super preferredFocusedView] : self.selectedViewController.preferredFocusedView;
}
- (void)didUpdateFocusInContext:(UIFocusUpdateContext *)context withAnimationCoordinator:(UIFocusAnimationCoordinator *)coordinator {
    [super didUpdateFocusInContext:context withAnimationCoordinator:coordinator];
    self.useDefaultFocusBehavior = YES;
}
@end

...

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    self.tabBarController.tabBar.hidden = YES; // or do it in storyboard
}
```

If you use storyboard for initial UI setup, don't forget to set custom class `TVTabBarController` to your tab bar controller there.

---

### Original solution:

Proposed approach with inheriting from `UITabBarController` didn't work for me because in fact `-preferredFocusedView` is called twice on startup, so I had to add a counter to return `self.selectedViewController.preferredFocusedView` for the first 2 calls. But it's a really hacky solution and there's no guarantee that it won't break in future.

So I found a much better solution: force focus update in appdelegate's `-applicationDidBecomeActive:` on the first call.

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    self.tabBarController.tabBar.hidden = YES;
}

- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application {
    static BOOL forceFocusToFirstTab = YES;
    if (forceFocusToFirstTab) {
        forceFocusToFirstTab = NO;
        [self.tabBarController.selectedViewController updateFocusIfNeeded];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I've found the solution, so if someone is interested, you just have to subclass `UITabBarController` and to override `preferredFocusedView`:

```
@interface ZTWTabBarController ()

@property (nonatomic, assign) BOOL firstTime;

@end

@implementation ZTWTabBarController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.firstTime = YES;
}

- (UIView *)preferredFocusedView {
    if (self.firstTime) {
        self.firstTime = NO;
        return self.selectedViewController.preferredFocusedView;
    }
    else {
        return [super preferredFocusedView];
    }
}

@end
```

Answer (score 1):

I was able to achieve this effect very simply with the `isHidden` property of the `UITabBar`.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.tabBar.isHidden = true
}
```

When the user scrolls up to display the tab bar, the `UITabBarController` will unhide it automatically.

Comment: At first, this appeared to work, but then I realized that simply hiding the tab bar doesn't move the focus to the tab bar item's view.

Answer (score 0):

This is the easiest & cleanest solution in my opinion:

```
override var preferredFocusedView: UIView? {
        if tabBar.hidden {
            return selectedViewController?.preferredFocusedView
        }
        return super.preferredFocusedView
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Since `preferredFocusedView` is deprecated in tvOS, you should override the `preferredFocusEnvironments` property instead

**Swift 4.0**

```
override var preferredFocusEnvironments: [UIFocusEnvironment] {
        if firsTime, let enviroments = selectedViewController?.preferredFocusEnvironments {
            firsTime = false
            return enviroments
        }
        return super.preferredFocusEnvironments
    }
```